# Several PhantomJS calls in a RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a RoR application that given a set of **N** URLs to parse, will perform **N** shell calls for a given PhantomJS (actually is a CasperJS) script.

So,

Right now I have something like this:

```
urls_to_parse = ['first.html', 'second.html',...]

urls_to_parse.each do |url|
  parse_results = \`casperjs parse_urls.js '#{url}'\`
end
```

I have never done this before. Launching shell scripts from a RoR/Ruby application, so I am wondering if this is a good approach and what alternative may I have. So, why I use PhantomJS in combination with RoR?

I basically have an API (RoR app) that keeps receiving urls that need to be parsed. They need to be parsed in a headless browser manner. The page actually needs to be rendered (that's why I don't use Nokogiri or any other HTML parser).

I am concerned about putting this up to production performance wise, and before going forward I would like to know if I am doing this correctly, or I can do it in a better way.

Comment: Some time has passed. Did you solve it differently than what you described? If yes, you could provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I thought about doing the same thing, but even with a headless browser I would be really concerned about the speed and bandwidth your server is going to need to have.   I use capser in conjuction with Python and it works very well for me.   I read stdout spit back from firing the casper scripts, but I don't parse and scrape on the fly like you're talking about doing.  I would imagine it's okay, but ideally you already have a cached database of results when people search.  Maybe if it is a very very basic search you'll be okay, but I don't know.

Comment: chawk, it's actually not a per-command service. I am thinking on using Delayed Jobs or Queues in order to process those commands. I just haven't been able to find a "server-side" headless browser, or a way to be able to find rendered elements in a site. For example, find the N <img> elements that are in the very top of the rendered page, not the HTML.

Comment: For my solutions I typically run processes locally then store data in a database on my public server.  I have python installed on my Ubuntu, so I don't see any reason why it would not be able to run Casper every hour or day or whatever you set it up to do.   I actually have a windows task which executes a python program every morning which calls the casper scripts.